# Create web base application(open url via browser) as APK file using Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have created an application using Cordova for android. But I am facing issue. If I opened APK file in android phone . Every time url is opened with new tab. I want that url open once in the browser, If I open that APK file many time in phone/tab (close app and reopen it).

Here is the code of index.js file:

```
var cordova_app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
onDeviceReady: function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
},
receivedEvent: function(id) {

}};

cordova_app.initialize();

function onDeviceReady(){
window.open("https://www.google.co.in/","_system");
navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

below is code of index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>abc</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: paste the code.

Comment: is it possible?